# using operators and functions for sql report charts (visual studio 2010)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reporting-services

I want to create some charts using sql reporting services. But i am unable to use a lot of functions and operators in combination with my data-fields

the following work(Stroke-data type is decimal):

```
> =Fields!Stroke.Value
> =Sum(Fields!Stroke.Value)
> =First(Fields!Stroke.Value)
> =Last(Fields!Stroke.Value)
> =2+2394.12
```

the following dont work:

```
> =Fields!Stroke.Value + 2
> =CStr(Fields!Stroke.Value)
> =CDbl(Fields!Stroke.Value)
> =Fields!Stroke.Value / Fields!Stroke.Value
> =Sum(Fields!Stroke.Value) * 2
```

all other operators and functions(using Fields!Stroke.Value) dont work too

Answer (score 0):

I've created a report with a histogram chart using this dummy data:

```
SELECT        'Accountant' AS JOB_TITLE, CAST(20.23 AS Decimal(5, 2)) AS FEE UNION ALL
SELECT        'Secretary' AS JOB_TITLE, CAST(45.83 AS Decimal(5, 2)) AS FEE UNION ALL
SELECT        'Manager' AS JOB_TITLE, CAST(21.55 AS Decimal(5, 2)) AS FEE UNION ALL
SELECT        'Helpdesk' AS JOB_TITLE, CAST(17.99 AS Decimal(5, 2)) AS FEE UNION ALL
SELECT        'Technician' AS JOB_TITLE, CAST(13.31 AS Decimal(5, 2)) AS FEE
```

When you create a chart in SSRS, you should at least have a field in the "Category Groups" section. In this case I've used the JOB_TITLE field in there.

In the SUM Values section of the chart data, you need to use some sort of aggregate or numeric literal.

I was able to successfully use all of these in the Sum Values section of the chart data:

```
=Fields!FEE.Value + 2
=CStr(Fields!FEE.Value)
=CDbl(Fields!FEE.Value)
=Fields!FEE.Value/Fields!FEE.Value
=SUM(Fields!FEE.Value) * 2
```

I'm surprised that `=CStr(Fields!FEE.Value)` works because strings don't have scale so mapping it to an axis makes no sense, but it seems to implicitly cope with it. 
It also makes no sense to use `=Fields!FEE.Value/Fields!FEE.Value` because all of your datapoints on the chart would be 1, unless your value is 0 in which case it would error.

I've verified here that all these functions do work when the records being queried are all decimals. I suspect that something in your data is causing these functions to break. Without knowing what your data looks like I can't assist any further.